# Django how to set custom properties for a ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have a forms.ModelForm 'CreateUserForm'.

I want to set a property for each form field to be later used in the template.

In this case, I want to set a icon name to specify which icon name should be used for each field.

```
class CreateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    icon_names = ['person', 'email', 'enhanced_encryption']

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

I've had trouble iterating over both the field AND the field's property 'icon_names'. I can't really [zip()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for) without losing functionality.

Currently I've hacked together iteration by using the 'forloop.parentloop.counter'

```
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-field">
            <i class="icons">
                {% for icon in form.icon_names %}
                    {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == forloop.counter %}
                        {{ icon }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </i>
            <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
            <label class="control-label" for="autocomplete-input">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which produces the intended result, but it seems redundant, especially if I wanted to add another field property in the future.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways i could do this both involving adding an extra html attribute on the fields widget

1. see **age** field below, i would use the **self.fields** to get the field widget and add the extra **icon** attribute on its **attrs** dictionary...for this to work you should ensure it comes after the call to `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` others the **self.fields** will not have been populated....i'd use this when i dont have anything else i need to adjust on the widget class.
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances
2. see **name** field below, You could do this on the Meta class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

The form

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['age'].widget.attrs['icon'] = 'age'

    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ('name', 'age')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'icon': 'email'})
        }
```

And on the template when looping over the fields id get it like this

```
{% for field in form %}
   {{ field.field.widget.attrs.icon }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to pass the `zip`ped list in the context, such as:

```
context = {'fields_with_icons': zip(form.icon_names, [field for field in form])}
```

and then

```
{% for field, icon in fields %}
{{ field }}
{{ icon }}
{% endfor %}
```